# Overlay smaller image in a larger image in OpenCV

Tags: opencv, javacv

I would like to replace a part of the image with my image in Opencv

I used

```
cvGetPerspectiveMatrix() with a warpmatrix and using cvAnd() and cvOr()
```

but could not get it to work

This is the code that is currently displaying the image and a white polygon for the replacement image. I would like to replace the white polygon for a pic with any dimension to be scaled and replaced with the region pointed.

While the code is in javacv I could convert it to java even if c code is posted

```
grabber.start();
while(isDisp() && (image=grabber.grab())!=null){
  if (dst_corners !=  null) {// corners of the image to be replaced
  CvPoint points = new CvPoint((byte) 0,dst_corners,0,dst_corners.length);
  cvFillConvexPoly(image,points, 4, CvScalar.WHITE, 1, 0);//white polygon covering the replacement image 
  }
correspondFrame.showImage(image);
}
```

Any pointers to this will be very helpful.

Update:

I used  warpmatrix with this code and I get a black spot for the overlay image

```
cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(x1,y1, overlay.width(), overlay.height()));
CvPoint2D32f p = new CvPoint2D32f(4);
CvPoint2D32f q = new CvPoint2D32f(4);

q.position(0).x(0);
q.position(0).y(0);
q.position(1).x((float) overlay.width());
q.position(1).y(0);
q.position(2).x((float) overlay.width());
q.position(2).y((float) overlay.height());
q.position(3).x(0);
q.position(3).y((float) overlay.height());

p.position(0).x((int)Math.round(dst_corners[0]);
p.position(0).y((int)Math.round(dst_corners[1]));
p.position(1).x((int)Math.round(dst_corners[2]));
p.position(1).y((int)Math.round(dst_corners[3]));
p.position(3).x((int)Math.round(dst_corners[4]));
p.position(3).y((int)Math.round(dst_corners[5]));
p.position(2).x((int)Math.round(dst_corners[6]));
p.position(2).y((int)Math.round(dst_corners[7]));

cvGetPerspectiveTransform(q, p, warp_matrix);

cvWarpPerspective(overlay, image, warp_matrix);
```

I get a black spot for the overlay image and even though the original image is a polygon with 4 vertices the overlay image is set as a rectangle. I believe this is because of the ROI. Could anyone please tell me how to fit the image as is and also why I am getting a black spot instead of the overlay image.

Comment: Is your polygon axis aligned (more specifically, rectangle)?

Comment: It is not a rectangle and it is not axis aligned, but it has only 4 vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `cvWarpPerspective`([link](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html?highlight=cvwarpperspective#warpperspective)) is what you are looking for.

So instead of doing

```
CvPoint points = new CvPoint((byte) 0,dst_corners,0,dst_corners.length);
cvFillConvexPoly(image,points, 4, CvScalar.WHITE, 1, 0);//white polygon covering the replacement image
```

Try

```
cvWarpPerspective(yourimage, image, M, image.size(), INTER_CUBIC, BORDER_TRANSPARENT);
```

Where `M` is the matrix you get from `cvGetPerspectiveMatrix`

Comment: Hi I am using cvGetPerspectiveTransform(q,p,warp_matrix); where p has the image corners and q has the overlay image corners. I am then using this warp_matrix for warpperspective but it still fails to replace the image. Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you paste your code? And what do you mean by "fails to replace"?

Comment: I added an update please check the code there :) As I said I want to fit an overlay image in a polygon with 4 vertices, not necessarily a rectangle. thanks for helping me

Comment: @PavanK I don't think you need to set ROI for image. And make sure the order of dst_corners is correct. You can print out warp_matrix to see if `cvGetPerspectiveTransform` gives you something reasonable.

Comment: If I dont set the ROI then whole image gets garbled. dst_corners have the correct corners as when I use convexpolyfill it fills perfectly. I'll print the warp_matrix to see if there are any problems there. I am really stuck here and I don't know whats going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to scale the pic to the white polygon size and then copy it to the grabbed image setting its Region of Interest (here is a [link](http://nashruddin.com/OpenCV_Region_of_Interest_%28ROI%29) explaining the ROI).
Your code should look like this:

```
resize(pic, resizedImage, resizedImage.size(), 0, 0, interpolation); //resizedImage should have the points size
cvSetImageROI(image, cvRect(the points coordinates));
cvCopy(resizedImage,image);
cvResetImageROI(image);
```

I hope that helps.

Best regards,
Daniel