# Creating a transparent mask with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

With the following code (which I have found in another stackoverflow post, and isn't mine), I am trying to copy a polygonal region from an image with the help of a mask. I am not very conversant with python's numpy array and having a very hard time figuring out how to create a transparent mask here. Currently, the code generates a black(#000000) mask. I have tried some post image processing with Python Wand something like that but the result is not desirable.

EDIT: here is the original post: [NumPy/OpenCV 2: how do I crop non-rectangular region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region/15343106)

Here is my python wand code:

```
from wand.image import Image
from wand.color import Color
from wand.drawing import Drawing
from wand.compat import nested

with Image(filename="image_masked.png") as img:
    img.format = "png"
    with Color("#000000") as black:
        twenty_percent = int(65535*0.2) # Note: percent must be calculated from Quantum
        img.transparent_color(black, alpha=0.0, fuzz=twenty_percent)
        img.save(filename="transparent.png")
```

here is the original code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# original image
# -1 loads as-is so if it will be 3 or 4 channel as the original
image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg', -1)
# mask defaulting to black for 3-channel and transparent for 4-channel
# (of course replace corners with yours)
mask = np.zeros(image.shape, dtype=np.uint8)
roi_corners = np.array([[(2320,330), (0,90), (0,450), (0,550)]],dtype=np.int32)
# fill the ROI so it doesn't get wiped out when the mask is applied
channel_count = image.shape[2]  # i.e. 3 or 4 depending on your image
ignore_mask_color = (255,)*channel_count
cv2.fillPoly(mask, roi_corners, ignore_mask_color)

# apply the mask
masked_image = cv2.bitwise_and(image, mask)

# save the result
cv2.imwrite('image_masked.png', masked_image)
cv2.imshow('image',masked_image)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Could you show your imports please? It's unclear what `Image` and `Color` are. Also, it would be a good idea to add a link to the original post.

Comment: @ai_m, I have updated post.

Comment: I would like to edit the original code a bit in order to produce transparent mask, if possible.