# Python : Determine if a pixel is sourrounded by a contiguous zone of an other color

Tags: python, opencv, scipy

I' have an a PNG image that i converted into a Numpy array with only ones and zero.
I want to find contiguous zones of 0 and that all the 1 that are on this contiguous zone are turned into 0.

I have got the contiguous zones with :

```
labels, num_features = label(temp)
```

But I have no idea on how to determine if a pixel is surrounded by a contiguous zone.

Note that I can't use dilation in my case to just fill the white as it damages the image in some other areas.

Here is an example : 0 is purple and 1 is white :
[image]

This is the result I'm looking for :

[image]

Comment: How about using floodfill?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [cv2.findContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gadf1ad6a0b82947fa1fe3c3d497f260e0), we may find the external contours, and then use [cv2.drawContours](https://docs.opencv.org/4.7.0/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga746c0625f1781f1ffc9056259103edbc) for filling the contours with the desired color.

The more interesting part is computing the "fill color" automatically (assume it's required).
Note: We may also assume that different contours in the same image may have different colors.

---

Assume we know the color from advance, use the following stages:

- Convert image to grayscale.
- Find contours (use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL for ignoring the inner contours).
- Iterate contours and draw a filled up contour over each contour.

Code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('contiguous_zones.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale.
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Apply automatic thresholding (use THRESH_OTSU) and invert polarity since background is white.

# Find contours (use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL for ignoring the inner contours).
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Iterate contours
for c in contours:
    # Draw contour over the original image with the mean color.
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, (177, 35, 159), -1)
```

---

Finding the color of each contour:

Based on the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54317652/4926757), we may find the average color inside a contour.
There is a small change - we have to ignore the white pixels inside the contour.
For improving the accuracy, we may also `erode` the mask a little.

Sample code for finding the color of contour `c`:

```
mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, 255, -1)
mask = mask & thresh  # Remove inner part from the mask (black pixels in thresh).
mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))  # Erode the mask for improving accuracy (there are few white pixels from the outer contour).
mean_color = cv2.mean(img, mask=mask)  # Compute the mean color of the pixels inside the mask.
mean_color = np.round(mean_color[0:3]).astype(int)  # Take first 3 elements applies BGR - (the 4'th element is alpha) and convert to int.
```

---

Complete code sample:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('contiguous_zones.png')

gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  # Convert to grayscale.
_, thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU + cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)  # Apply automatic thresholding (use THRESH_OTSU) and invert polarity since background is white.

# Find contours (use cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL for ignoring the inner contours).
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Iterate contours
for c in contours:
    # Get the average color inside a contour
    # The mean color excludes the inner white pixels
    ############################################################################
    # https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316588/get-the-average-color-inside-a-contour-with-open-cv
    mask = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]), np.uint8)
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [c], 0, 255, -1)
    mask = mask & thresh  # Remove inner part from the mask (black pixels in thresh).
    mask = cv2.erode(mask, np.ones((5, 5), np.uint8))  # Erode the mask for improving accuracy (there are few white pixels from the outer contour).
    #cv2.imshow('mask', mask)  # Show mask for testing
    #cv2.waitKey()
    mean_color = cv2.mean(img, mask=mask)  # Compute the mean color of the pixels inside the mask.
    mean_color = np.round(mean_color[0:3]).astype(int)  # Take first 3 elements applies BGR - (the 4'th element is alpha) and convert to int.
    ############################################################################

    # Draw contour over the original image with the mean color.
    cv2.drawContours(img, [c], 0, mean_color.tolist(), -1)


# Show results for testing:
cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('img', img)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

---

`img` (output):
[image]

`thresh`:
[image]