# Cut Image with different Coordinates non-rectangular

Tags: python, crop, opencv

I want to cut a region in a picture with different coordinates.

I have points like that:

```
  <point x="720" y="549" />
  <point x="805" y="665" />
  <point x="715" y="698" />
  <point x="644" y="582" />
```

And I want to use them to get a new picture without a mask in the background or something like that. Only the Region from this coordinates.
I have something like that:
[NumPy/OpenCV 2: how do I crop non-rectangular region?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region)
But I can not transform it, to my solution.
Maybe someone of you can help me.

Thank you!
Felix

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution with this
https://jdhao.github.io/2019/02/23/crop_rotated_rectangle_opencv/

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do something like:

> img = img.crop((150, 150, 230, 350))

Where the first 2 coordinates(x,y) are the top left corner and the 2 last coordinates(x,y) are bottom right corner of it.

Note the coordinates are given in pixels.

Comment: Yes, I tried that, but that only counts for rectangle cuts. My coordinates are not rectangles.

Comment: Have you tried what is described in the answer in this link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341538/numpy-opencv-2-how-do-i-crop-non-rectangular-region

Comment: Yes, I linked it in my original question. I want only the the not-masked part of the picture. Not more.